# Account not found after creating one

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid

When making an account for Stack exchange, I received a email for confirming my account. After doing this, I tried login in on the mobile app. I recieved a message saying "account not found".

Comment: Could you post the screenshot please?

Comment: Which mobile app?

Comment: It's been resolved somehow. Thanks anyways! The mobile app was Stack Exchange.

Comment: So probably you should've blamed caching :)

Comment: @user471859 in the future, you should mention if you mean iOS app or android app. We can't possibly guess and it's crucial info.